# Create a node programmatically on installing a module

Tags: nodes, installation

I would like to have my module to create new nodes (page) when being installed and removing these pages on uninstall.

I tried the following with no success in my mymodule.install file:

```
<?php

function mymodule_install() {

  $node = new stdClass(); // We create a new node object
  $node->type = "page"; // Or any other content type you want
  $node->title = "Your title goes jere";
  $node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE; // Or any language code if Locale module is enabled. More on this below *
  $node->uid = 1; // Or any id you wish
  $node->path = array('alias' => 'your_node_path'); // Setting a node path
  node_object_prepare($node); // Set some default values.

  // Let's add standard body field
  $node->body[$node->language][0]['value'] = 'This is a body text';
  $node->body[$node->language][0]['summary'] = 'Here goes a summary';
  $node->body[$node->language][0]['format'] = 'filtered_html'; // If field has a format, you need to define it. Here we define a default filtered_html format for a body field

  $node = node_submit($node); // Prepare node for a submit
  node_save($node); // After this call we'll get a nid  

}
```

This code is cut n' paste from [this page](http://timonweb.com/how-programmatically-create-nodes-comments-and-taxonomies-drupal-7).

When I disable/enable the module, the page is not created (at least it does not appear in Content and in the node table of the database).

How should I do it please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that install/uninstall and enable/disable are two separate things in Drupal.

When you enable or disable a module, [`hook_enable()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_enable/7) and [`hook_disable()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_disable/7) are invoked respectively.

When you install or uninstall a module, [`hook_install()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_install/7) and [`hook_uninstall()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_uninstall/7) are invoked respectively.

If you want to keep your code in `hook_install()` / `hook_uninstall()` you'll need to disable the module, and then uninstall it at http://mysite.com/admin/modules/uninstall. Once you re-install it (which will also enable it), your code will be run.

It might be worth having a think if this code would be better served in `hook_enable()` / `hook_disable()`, but it will depend on your particular situation.

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding of the API Clive. And thank you for your help, it works beautifully. I will put in hook_disable() some lines to delete the content created in the _enable() function now. Do you have any recommendation or good practice to keep track (in hook_enable()) of the node ID to be deleted (in hook_disable())?

Comment: Note: in Drupal 8 these methods have been consolidated. There is no `hook_enable` or `hook_disable` anymore, just `hook_install` and `hook_uninstall`. See details here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2193013